# JQuery mobile : enlarge and decrease height of text area on user type

Tags: jquery, mobile

i'm working on Android application Chat .. i have a textarea in chat form i need this text area too resize height automatically while user type inside and when user remove text from inside the textarea
any help or suggestion for this issue !!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

textarea autogrow functionality is called on its keyup event.so textarea will start growing when user start entering the text inside it. Note that Textarea will only grow but they will not shrink.

You can **[Refer This](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-textarea-autogrow)** discussion from jquery forum.

Comment: i need it to grow and shrink and also can set a height for the textarea...similar to What's up chat application on mobile

any Results ???